# uWSGI - Can't stop 2 helper threads properly?

Tags: python, multithreading, uwsgi

I create 1 worker thread for each uWSGI process, and 1 helper thread for the first uWSGI process:

```
def post_fork():
    if uwsgi.worker_id() == 1:
        webapp.start_helper()
    webapp.start_worker()

uwsgi.post_fork_hook = post_fork
```

At exit, I try to close the helper and all the workers:

```
def at_exit():
    webapp.shutdown()

uwsgi.atexit = at_exit

class WebApp(object):
    def shutdown(self):
        self.worker.stop()
        if self.helper:
            self.helper.stop()
```

The issue is that helper is never stopped. I discovered that if I change the order of helper and worker in the shutdown method, the helper will be stopped, but the worker thread for that process will instead not be stopped:

```
class WebApp(object):
        def shutdown(self):
            if self.helper:
                self.helper.stop()
            self.worker.stop()
```

So my question is... why wouldn't they both be stopped?

How can I stop both?

P.S. - Here's the stop() code (roughly the same for worker and helper):

```
class Worker(object):
    def stop(self):
        logger.info("Stopping!")
        if self.thread:
            self.stop_worker = True   # exits the main loop on the next iteration
            logger.info("Joining thread...")
            self.thread.join()
```

I can get a "Stopping!" from 3 workers and 1 helper or from 4 workers.

P.P.S. - The definitely all get started. :-)

Comment: Did you consider using a daemon thread?